# Recarregar apenas uma DIV com Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Olá. Estou utilizando LARAVEL.

Possuo uma div que exibe se o site está ON ou OFF.
Utilizando a função curl_info, é passada a url e então a função retorna o status do site.

Gostaria que essa div ficasse sendo atualizada constantemente para verificar quando o site fica OFF. Como atualizar apenas esta div e não o site todo com Javascript?

PHP

```
public function curl_info($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $info = curl_getinfo( $ch );

        if ($info['http_code']==200 ) {
                return "ON";
                } else {
                return "OFF";
                }

    }
```

```html
<div class="col-3 text-center font-weight-bold border border-light {!! app(App\Http\Controllers\monitController::class)->curl_info('http://google.com.br') !!}" id="meupc">
            SITE

            <p>{!! app(App\Http\Controllers\monitController::class)->curl_info('http://google.com.br') !!}</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: *setInterval* + *AJAX*

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Como executar o método de tempos em tempos, como atualizar a div ou como fazer o curl?

Comment: Só para confirmar, você alterar a div assim você sabe? $('#suaDiv').text('conteudo')     OU em JS: document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = "novo conteudo da div";

Answer (score 0):

Tente incrementar isso em seu código, só que ao invés de deixar a execução da `function myFunction()`  em um `button`, deixa em no `onload` do `body`.

```js
function myFunction() {
setInterval(function(){
  console.log("executando")
},1000)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```